# calling javascript class function from onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple class that has a few methods(for now). I can instantiate it and call the init function, but I cant call another method from the `onchange` attribute.

here is the class:

```
var ScheduleViewer = (function() {
var options = {
  container: 'trip_stops',
  schedule: {}
};

function ScheduleViewer (){};

ScheduleViewer.prototype.init = function(params) {
  $.extend(options, params);
  // setTimeout(function() {
  //   ScheduleViewer.addListener(options);
  // }, 3000);
  this.addListener(options);
}

ScheduleViewer.prototype.getSchedule = function(trip_id) {
  var _id = trip_id;
  console.log(_id);
}

ScheduleViewer.prototype.addListener = function(options) {
  console.log("adding listener");
   var _id = options.select_id;
   console.log($('#train_select').length);// zero assuming timing issue
   $('#'+_id).on('change', function() {
     alert("changed");
   })
}
return ScheduleViewer;
})();
```

the call

```
<div id="trip_stops" class="trip_options">
        <% if (trips.length > 0) {  %>
            <%
                var params = {
                schedule: schedule
              };
              var scheduler = new ScheduleViewer();
              scheduler.init(params);
            %>
            <select id="train_select">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>Select a train</option>
                <% $.each(trips, function(index, val) { %>
                    <option value="<%= val.trip_id %>">
                        <%= val.train_num %> Train
                    </option>
                <% }); %>
            </select>
        <% } else { %>
            No trips scheduled.
        <% } %>
    </div>
```

Note that Im using jqote for templating.

I get the log from the init call, but then fails in the `onchange` with `Uncaught ReferenceError: scheduler is not defined`. Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Any pointers?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I made an attempt to add a listener that gets called at initialization. Im assuming that because of timing issues the listener is not getting bind. Now this is where my inexperience comes in play I tried to `setTimeout` but the function call is not happening as is.

Comment: What's the stuff between `<% %>`? Server-side JScript?

Comment: @bfavaretto I think it's like **ASP.NET** or something

Comment: jqote = javascript templating.

Comment: So I believe what you declare inside the template tags is preprocessed, and not available in the global scope to an inline onchange attribute.

Comment: Why does every `ScheduleViewer` instance have the same options? And notice that `schedule` in your `params` object *is* undefined.

Comment: @Bergi The options will not change with the exception of `schedule` which is not shown in here but its a json object.

Comment: @LouieV: OK, but if they don't change you might better make `init` a static function and call it only once outside of the loop.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah makes sense. I think Im going to create the class inside the `window` object as someone mention before. So it be like `window.ScheduleViewer = (function(){})();` with static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve the issue I ended up adding the class to the window object. I had issues with the listeners as the code that loads the template was not fast enough and the binding was not happening.

The class looks like:

```
window.ScheduleViewer = (function() {
var options = {
  container: 'trip_stops',
  schedule: {}
};

this.init = function(params) {
  $.extend(options, params); 
}

this.getSchedule = function(trip_id) {
  var _id = trip_id;
  //Do some cool stuff with GTFS data
}
//More functions

return this;
})();
```

The templated html:

```
<div id="trip_stops" class="trip_options">
        <% if (trips.length > 0) {  %>
            <%
                var params = {
                schedule: schedule
              };
              ScheduleViewer.init(params);
            %>
            <select id="train_select" onchange="ScheduleViewer.getSchedule(this.value)">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>Select a train</option>
                <% $.each(trips, function(index, val) { %>
                    <option value="<%= val.trip_id %>">
                        <%= val.train_num %> Train
                    </option>
                <% }); %>
            </select>
        <% } else { %>
            No trips scheduled.
        <% } %>
    </div>
```

Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this may not work, but you shouldn't really use inline styles/functions anyway.

Why don't you try and get the element in your script the apply the `onchange` **function** to it.

```
var scheduler = new ScheduleViewer();
    select = document.getElementById('train_select');

scheduler.init(params);

select.onchange = function() {
   scheduler.getSchedule(this.value)
};
```

Comment: Ill try to add a listener. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the event in javascript and remove the inline event.

```
var scheduler = new ScheduleViewer();
scheduler.init(params);

$(document).on('change', '#select', function() {
   scheduler.getSchedule(this.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jQote before, however could it be because of the way jQote handles variable declarations? Try instanciating your `scheduler` object outside the templating code.

```
<script>
var scheduler = new ScheduleViewer(),
    params = { schedule: schedule };

scheduler.init(params);
</script>

<!-- template code... -->
```

**Also please note that the way you have written your code, all ScheduleViewer instances will share the same `options` object.** I am not sure what you will be doing with this `options` object, but I guess that's not the desired behaviour.

Finally, like already stated by others, adding event listeners inline is a bad practice and you should register your even handlers programmatically using JavaScript. Either with the native `addEventListener` function or with helper functions of your favorite library.

Comment: @Connor, It appears to be his client-side templating library. http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jqote, but it looks like a scoping problem.  If you must use the inline onchange, put the object reference in the window object and access it from there.

```
window['scheduler'] = new ScheduleViewer();
window['scheduler'].init(params);
```

And

```
<select id="train_select" onchange="window['scheduler'].getSchedule(this.value)">
```

Comment: These are all the same, so which one do you prefer? `scheduler = new ScheduleViewer();` **| OR |**  `window.scheduler = new ScheduleViewer();` **| OR |** `window['scheduler'] = new ScheduleViewer();`

Comment: They're the same if the jqote section is not changing the scope of scheduler declaration.  If the declaration were in a script tag I would not be proposing this.

Comment: Still dot notation is better, ie `window.scheduler`